# Cursor flickering/vanishing in XFCE, even with display compositing off

Tags: debian, xfce, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cursor

I am running XFCE4 with Raspbian (essentially Debian) on my Raspberry Pi. I read here on Stack Exchange that turning display compositing off should resolve my problem, which it didn't. Also I would like to keep display compositing on (if possible) since Docky looks ugly without it. :P 
Do I need to turn some other graphic features down/off to improve performance, or is this just an RPi thing? (Note: When I used LXDE on Raspbian with compositing on I didn't have this problem)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe provide a link to what you read about turning off compositing. What compositor are you using? Compton, something built in with xfce? Can you provide the compositing configuration such as what you see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468&page=2). If it's not the compositor what other peculiar configuration you have could interfere?

Comment: @Amphiteót [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/402692/mouse-cursor-dissappearing-flickering-when-not-moving-xubuntu-12-04-xfce-4-10) is the link, the default built-into Xfce (turned on through Settings) and I'm not on my Pi ATM so I'll edit this post once I know

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in the end of 2019. I have been facing this issue since the day I installed an OS on my RPi. I have used Both Raspbian (LXDE), Ubuntu Mate and Arch Linux (LXDE and XFCE). On the Arch Linux, I have tried the default composition turned both on and off, and even tried picom (Compton) compositor. I have also tried different cursor themes. The cursor flickering never goes away. However, disabling the composition makes the cursor flicker less often, maybe twice a second while dragging / resizing a window. Otherwise, it flickers 6 - 10 times a second.